# Locking is not possible in the directory "/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi"

Tags: permissions, eclipse

I installed Eclipse 4.3 to my Ubuntu 13.04 and it works perfect when I am root. However when I try to run Eclipse without root authorization, I receive the following error message:

```
Locking is not possible in the directory "/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi". A common reason is that the file system or Runtime Environment does not support file locking for that location. Please choose a different location, or disable file locking passing "-Dosgi.locking=none" as a VM argument. 
/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock (Permission denied)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I personally had no problems installing and running Eclipse to `/opt/eclipse`. I had no problems running as a normal user. Try reinstalling Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

Take ownership on the whole directory:
    `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`

Comment: works also on 14.04

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't have permissions to modify `/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock`. You should change the user owner of the file using:

```
 sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when Eclipse cannot write to the configuration area it will assume you have a shared installation and create a private configuration area in the user's home directory. So why does it still try to write to the shared configuration area in some cases?
I had the same problem (which is what brought me here) but found the solution here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/206634/661552/#msg_661552 If parts of the shared configuration area are writable, Eclipse will not use the private configuration area. Maybe this information can still be of use to someone.